# Where is libpython-dev?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, python

I've just upgraded to 12.04 and I can't find `libpython-dev` anymore.

Can you tell me where it is?

Comment: There is no `libpython-dev` [for any release](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=libpython). Are you looking for `libpython2.7-dev`?

Answer (score 3):

rmadison can't find libpython-dev, so it looks like it doesn't exist, maybe you're looking for python-dev?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right Thank you for your quick reply!

Comment: @SamuelKortas: please accept this answer if you found it helpful